# In python: how to create new column with value of column and value of another between brackets. New column= column1(column2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a data frame with counts in a column and percentages in another. I want to create new column in this data frame presenting counts(percentages).

example data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'count': [1,2,3],
    'percent': [30,35,35]})
print(df)
```

while I want the result like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'count': [1,2,3],
    'percent': [30,35,35], 'count(percent)': ['1(30)', '2(35)', '3(35)']})
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this line:

```
  df["count(percent)"] = df["count"].astype(str) +'('+df["percent"].astype(str)+')'
```